# Deploying First application with jboss and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm trying to deploy my first application with jboss in Eclipse, I have copied the same example we can find in Maven Projects examples and when I deploy the application I have this on my Eclipse and I don't see anything, just that it's not available:

```
11:28:55,677 Información [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:28:59,246 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:28:59,541 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
11:29:13,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:29:13,458 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
11:29:13,495 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
11:29:13,608 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
11:29:14,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
11:29:14,210 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
11:29:14,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
11:29:14,245 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:29:14,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
11:29:14,411 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:29:14,701 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
11:29:15,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
11:29:20,649 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:29:21,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:29:21,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:29:25,487 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Arrancando Coyote HTTP/1.1 en puerto http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
11:29:29,269 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
11:29:33,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss\standalone\deployments
11:29:33,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:29:33,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found jboss-as-helloworld2.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called jboss-as-helloworld2.war.dodeploy
11:29:33,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
11:29:33,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
11:29:34,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jboss-as-helloworld2.war"
11:29:39,145 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /jboss-as-helloworld2
11:29:39,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:29:39,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 45293ms - Started 172 of 249 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
11:29:39,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "jboss-as-helloworld2.war"
```

Why?. Thanks so much and regards

Comment: What do you mean 'not available?' That console log looks good to me. What happens when you go to http://localhost:8080/jboss-as-helloworld2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Port 9990 is actually used by the **Admin Console**. Your application is accessible on port 8080 as stated by your log

localhost-127.0.0.1-8080

If you can't reach your application on localhost:8080/jboss-as-helloworld2 check out first that your application has a default web page (index.jsp/index.html)